# How to determine if a user has entered only date or also time in the form field?

Tags: date, asp-classic

I have a field where user can enter only date or also time in a text field. Now I know if I make 2 fields, one for date and one for time, I can check if the time field is empty or not.

What I'd like to do is have only one field. If user puts the ending date it takes time only, if user inputs date and time it takes both.

The problem I have is this: If user enters "8.12.2013" it in fact means "8.12.2013 0:0:0" where I convert it to Cdate. But then the end time is the first second of the date 8.12.2013 which means it 8.12.2013 means stop on that date (this is a stop time field). But in fact if a user writes 8.1.2013 it means roll till the end of the day.

Of course I can do date()>"8.12.2013" and it will work, but then if user enters date and time it will not work as it strips time part.

My question: Is there any function in ASP that would check if the time part of the date is set in a variable? I tried to use TIME but it shows 0 for hours, 0 for minutes and 0 for seconds even if the Cdate("8.12.2013") is used. I'd need the function to tell me that the time is not set so I could make a comparation using date() instead of now().

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: maybe just set a maxlength on the text field so people can't type enough characters to include a time? Also, you could / should just validate the text field with javascript to ensure it's just a date and say "hey just give me a date"

Comment: Additionally, you could just treat it as a string and split it on the space and take the first half (Before the space) and ditch the rest.

Comment: What format can the user enter the date in?  (I.E.  Always mm.dd. yyyy) or do you allow other formats.   If the format is predictable, then split the date on the period into an array.   If the array size is 3 and last element is 2 or 4 chars long, they only entered a date...

Comment: I would not like to ditch anything, I'd like to know if user entered datetime or date only.

Comment: If IsDate(var) returns true and Instr(var,":") returns > 0, you have a time in var

Comment: Hm, thank you, this may work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as simple as:

```
If CLng(myDate) = myDate Then ...
```

Dates are treated as time past a particular date etc., therefore integerising the date will remove the time.

-- EDIT --

Just to add to the above code:  The `CLng` will convert a Date *and* Time into just a Date.  By comparing this against the whole date you can see if any fractional part was included.

Please be aware that this would be considered bad practice in a strictly typed environment, such as .NET, but Classic ASP types are variants and are quite malleable.

Comment: But I don't want to remove the time at all. I'd like to see if time is also in a field or not.

Comment: This won't remove the times from the dates it simply tests to see if a time is present.  Try the code and see if it works for you.